# Removing None and terminating in python?

Tags: python

The following is my code:

```
def interact():

    d = c.split()
    while True: 
        if d[0] =='date' and len(d) == 2: 
            print display_stats(d[1])
        elif c == 'q':
            return
        else:
            print "Unknown Command: ",c
        break
```

However, when I run my code I get the following with a None:

```
Welcome to calculator


Maximum Power Outputs:

Building 1               351.2kW
Building 2               7.0kW
Building 3               275.9kW
Building 4               269.1kW            
None
```

Please help on fixing the code and removing None! Also in the `elif`, if the `raw_input = 'x'`, the x command should cause the program to terminate. So how would I fix that issue as well?

Comment: Is the 'None' coming from your display_stats function ? What is that code ?

Answer (score 2):

The `None` you're seeing is the result of your display_stats() function. All Python functions return a value, even functions with no explicit `return` statement; if they have no `return` statement, the value they return is `None`. So this is the line that's printing `None`:

```
            print display_stats(d[1])
```

Change that to:

```
            display_stats(d[1])
```

and the `None` should be gone.

As for your other question, replace:

```
    elif c == 'q':
```

with:

```
    elif c in ('q', 'x'):
```

and that should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Just asking why is it this "elif c in ('q', 'x'):" instead of  elif c == 'q':?

Comment: @Pythonaddict - I assumed that you wanted to quit with *either* 'q' or 'x' as the command, so I showed you how to check a string for multiple values at once. If you only want 'x' to exit the program but not 'q', then you should just have `elif c == 'q':` (basically, replace 'x' with 'q' in your existing line).

Comment: @Pythonaddict - Also, Burhan Khalid's advice is good too when he suggests to put the `if c == 'q':` (or `if c == 'x':`) line right after your call to `raw_input()`, because if you're going to exit the program, there's no point in running the rest of the function.

Answer (score 1):

If a method in Python has no `return` statement, the default value returned is `None`. This is what you are seeing.

To stop this from happening, just add a return value. For your other part, to quit the application, just check first if the person want to quit, before the rest of your loop starts.

```
import sys

def interact():
    print "Welcome to calculator"
    print
    c = raw_input("Command: ")
    # Just do the check here, so you don't bother running the rest of the code
    if c == 'x':
       sys.exit()
    print
    d = c.split()
    while True: 
        if d[0] =='date' and len(d) == 2: 
            print display_stats(d[1])
        elif c == 'q':
            return
        else:
            print "Unknown Command: ",c
        break
    return '' # Return a blank string
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your program exit, and remove the None :

```
import sys

def interact():
   print "Welcome to calculator"
   print
   c = raw_input("Command: ")
   print
   d = c.split()
   while True: 
        if d[0] =='date' and len(d) == 2: 
           display_stats(d[1])
        elif c == 'q':
           return
        elif c == 'x':
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print "Unknown Command: ",c
        break
```

The None appears since the display_stats already does the printing, and then returns something - all functions do, and it is likely that it returns None, which is then printed in your interact function: I have simply removed the print before the display_stats call.